# Conversion Tracking: GoogleAdwords tracking pixel vs. Google-Analytics + GoogleAdowords + Goal-Import

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-ads-api

I'm a little confused. Are there two different ways to track conversions on my Website?
First I found to track conversions only with my AdWords-Tool with a code on http://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722054?hl=en:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 1234567890;
var google_conversion_format = "1";
var google_conversion_color = "666666";
var google_conversion_label = "Purchase";
if (10.0) {
var google_conversion_value = 10.0
}
/* ]]> */ 
</script>
```

But I thought this is much easier if you just set up goals in your Google-Analytics-Account link your Google-Analytics-Accoutn to your AdWords-Account and import the Goals from Google-Analytics to GoogleAdwords? (Because you have only the tracking-code from google implemented in your website)

Do you need both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you need both?

No, you do not need both.  The Second way is best if you're using GA; the first is for if you have a different analytics provider.